# 2020 Australian Maths Competition Senior Problem 30

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, combinatorics-on-words

When I drive to school every day, I pass eight traffic lights, each either green, yellow,
or red. I find that, because of synchronization, a green light is always followed
immediately by a yellow, and a red light is never immediately followed by a red.
Thus a sequence of lights may start with GYRY, but not RRGG.
How many possible sequences of the eight lights are there?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: You may try to represent the transitions by a matrix. Dynamic programming approach

Comment: Can a yellow light be followed by any of red, green, or yellow? If it were yellow, how would you know it?

Comment: A yellow light can be followed by any color in the problem.

Comment: Math Lover I split the problem in a number cases based on the number of green lights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’m not good at math or English. I hope the following notations are not confusing, and my answer helps.

Let $f(n)$ represents the number of all possible sequences of $n$ lights.

If $n=0$, then the sequences are $\{ \emptyset \}$. Thus

$$
f(0) = 1
$$

If $n=1$, then the sequences are $\{ R , G, Y \}$. Thus

$$
f(1) = 3
$$

If $n=2$, then the sequences are $\{ RG, RB, GY, YR, RG, YY \}$. Thus,

$$
f(2) = 6
$$

If $n \ge 3$, then

$$\begin{align}
f(n) &= f_{R}(n-1) + f_{G}(n-1) + f_{Y}(n-1)\\
&= f_{RG}(n-2) + f_{RY}(n-2) + f_{GY}(n-2) + f_{Y}(n-1)\\
&= f_{RGY}(n-3) + f_{RY}(n-2) + f_{GY}(n-2) + f_{Y}(n-1)\\
&= f(n-3) + 2f(n-2) + f(n-1)\\
\end{align}
$$

I wrote a function in Python to compute the result. It told me $f(8)=595$.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved through recursive combinatorics, let's call:

$$G_n=\text{ valid sequences of lights long } n \text{ that terminate with G}$$
$$Y_n=\text{ valid sequences of lights long } n \text{ that terminate with Y}$$
$$R_n=\text{ valid sequences of lights long } n \text{ that terminate with R}$$

You can find out that(if you don't know how tell me and I'll help you):

$$G_{n+1}=Y_n+R_n$$
$$Y_{n+1}=G_n+R_n+Y_n$$
$$R_{n+1}=Y_{n}$$
And clearly $G_1=Y_1=R_1=1$